# In SIFT, how is the coordinate system being rotated?

Tags: image-processing, feature-extraction, c++, opencv, sift

I need to understand how SIFT calculates the descriptors for the keypoints.

Intuitively, I understand that it takes each keypoint, calculates the gradients for each pixel in a neighborhood of the keypoint, and that's basically the descriptor for the keypoint. The paper mentions a coordination system rotation in the keypoint, I assume this is when the image is rotated, the keypoint descriptor doesn't change.

**My question:**

I'm following [this implementation of SIFT](https://gist.github.com/lxc-xx/7088609#file-sift-cpp-L540,L541). In the part of the calculation function, there is this cos/sin calculation:
I think this is related to the coordinate system rotation. Can you explain how the coordinate system is being rotated? Why does that have to do with the `hist_width`?

Comment: Found this in-depth explanation for every step of the SIFT algo: https://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2014/82/article.pdf